# Convert Ionic sidemenu with dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I am working on ionic project and I am trying to convert side menu into dropdown menu instead.

I created ionic app using `ionic start appname sidemenu` command.

Currently, the default behaviour is when I click on hamburger link to open menu then a menu slides from left to right.

But I want it something like

[this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlWIt.png)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you are using `ionic 3+`  then you could utilize the [`PopoverController`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/popover/PopoverController/)

So now you would have

```
<button ion-button icon-only (click)="presentPopover($event)">
  <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

then your Main page where you want to render it

```
import { PopoverController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({})
class MyPage {
  constructor(public popoverCtrl: PopoverController) {}

  presentPopover(myEvent) {
    let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(PopoverPage);
    popover.present({
      ev: myEvent
    });
  }
}
```

Then your menu would be

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <ion-list>
      <ion-list-header>Ionic</ion-list-header>
      <button ion-item (click)="close()">Home</button>
      <button ion-item (click)="close()">Services</button>
      <button ion-item (click)="close()">Contact</button>
    </ion-list>
  `
})
class PopoverPage {
  constructor(public viewCtrl: ViewController) {}

  close() {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But how can I disable the default left slide menu? Right when I click on hamburger icon then it shows the default menu as well as popover.